Existence of hypersurfaces in projective space not containing any lines
Let $k$ be a field. Under what assumptions on $k$ is the following true?
There exists a hypersurface $H$ of $\mathbb P_k^n$ such that $H$ does not contain any line?
By a hypersurface, I mean an algebraic hypersurface, i.e., "cut out" by a homogeneous polynomial in $k[x_0,\dots,x_n]$ of positive degree. I don't care about the degree of the hypersurface.
Such hypersurfaces exist if $k = \bar k$, as discussed in this post. But I am specifically interested in the case $k = \mathbb F_p$ for a prime $p$. If such hypersurfaces do not exist for this choice of $k$, the following weaker statement would be sufficient for my purposes.
For every large enough $n$, there exists a closed subscheme $X$ of $\mathbb P_k^n$ of dimension $n - O(1)$ such that $X$ does not contain any linear subspace of codimension $\mathrm{dim} X$.
EDIT (2024-06-13): Here is a version of the second statement avoiding big-$O$ notation since that is ambiguous in this context.
There exists a constant $c \in \mathbb N$ such that for every large enough $n$, there exists a closed subscheme $X$ of $\mathbb P_k^n$ of dimension $n - c$ such that $X$ does not contain any linear subspace of dimension $c$.

Did you mean to write dimension $n-h^0(O(1))$ or something like that in your last paragraph?

@TabesBridges: I think $n-O(1)$ means a function of $n$ which differs from $n$ by a constant not depending on $n$ (nothing to do with the line bundle $O(1)$).

@LazzaroCampeotti I suppose that does make more sense, and did cross my mind, but I cannot recall the last time I saw big O notation used in an AG context!

Over a finite field this can probably be done by counting, assuming that by a line you mean a line defined over $k$: Given a line, count the number of hypersurfaces of degree $d$ over $k$ containing it and then multiply this number by the number of lines (over $k$). If $d$ is sufficiently large this will be greater than the number of all hypersurfaces of degree $d$.

@LazzaroCampeotti is exactly right about the interpretation of O(1). Sorry for the ambiguous notation.
